# What does this quote "It is always the latest song that an audience applauds the most" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

This is a quote from Homer. I was wondering what doest it mean, the word "latest" means "last" or "newest"?

Comment: It means 'most recent'.

Comment: yeap, "latest" surely literally means "most recent", and it that case what does the whole sentence mean? Do it logically mean "last song"?

Comment: Yes, the last song in the list. If you're talking about the most recent one, you're supposed to logically  infer that the audience has heard a number of songs. Then Homer is referring to the last one (the latest, the most recent) of them. I don't agree with the literal sentiment; I think people applaud the one one that has been played the most. Other people might prefer the older songs. But whatever the choice, I think he's at least saying that people don't applaud as much the _best_ song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from Odissey Book I:

> We cannot blame Phemius if he chooses to sing of the Danaans' tragic
>   fate, for it is always the latest song that an audience applauds the
>   most. You must be brave and nerve yourself to listen, for Odysseus is
>   not the only one who has never returned from Troy

And means that we cannot blame Phemius for he's telling about sad stories, because he is not responsible for them (the gods are), and because the newer is the song, the better is for the audience. So let him sing.